# Adding repaint() method to JFrame or Viewer?

Tags: java, jframe, repaint

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class ChessRunner implements MouseListener
{  

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static int colFrom;
    private static int rowFrom;
    private static int colTo;
    private static int rowTo;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        ChessViewer theImgTester = new ChessViewer(); 
        frame.add(theImgTester);
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){

            }

            /**
             * Gets initial mouse click position, translates it to row and column
             */
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
                colFrom = (int)((event.getX()/45));
                rowFrom = (int)(9-(event.getY()/45));
            }
            /**
             * Set the new row and column after mouse is released.
             */
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
            colTo = (int)(event.getX()/45);
            rowTo = (int)(9-event.getY()/45);


            theImgTester.getBoard().move(rowFrom,colFrom,rowTo,colTo);
            theImgTester.getBoard().print();
            theImgTester.repaint();
            frame.repaint();
        }
        });
    }   
}
```

This is a board game with pieces on it.

Here, I want my graphics to repaint when I finish dragging.
I have a nongraphical version (text-based) in the console that shows the piece moving.
I've added the repaint() method to both the JFrame and the Component(theImgTester).

ChessViewer theImgTester is a component that has both the pieces and the board.
I am trying to get the repaint() method to work.
Do I need to change anything in the ChessViewer? I'm pretty sure the problem lies within this file though.
Please give me some hints!

EDIT: ChessViewer.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ChessViewer extends JComponent{
    private JLabel turn = new JLabel();


    private ChessBoard board;

    /**
     * Constructor for the chess viewer.
     * Constructs a new chessboard.
     */
        public ChessViewer() {
        board= new ChessBoard();
        board.start();
    }


    /**
     * Returns the chessboard
     * @return
     */
    public ChessBoard getBoard(){
        return board;
    }




    /**
     * Method to print the chessboard and pieces on the chessboard.
     */
    public void paint(Graphics h) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)h;

        board.paint(g);
        for(int i = 0; i < board.getSizeB(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<board.getSizeB(); j++){
                board.getBoard()[j][i].paint(h);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me how you added the `repaint()` methode on `theImgTester`? (is `theImgTester` a subclass of `awt.component`?)

Comment: If I recall, there is already a `repaint` method

Comment: do you know how `theImgTester` is implemented @niceman? maybe we can find the problem there?

Comment: @MartinFrank how could I know ?!! but yes the problem must be there, I feel he defined repaint method on his own and either forgot to call `super.repaint()` or he hid the super's function instead of overriding it.  
"If I recall" I meant from my knowledge of java.

Comment: @niceman that's what i was thinking, but i didn't dare to write it out! thank you for your bravery! i think you are right! let's see whats written in the class of the instance of `theImgTester`

Comment: theImgTester is a subclass of JComponent.
I've uploaded theImgTester class.
It is basically just gathering all the images to the component.

Comment: ChessBoard class has a paint() method, but it is not a subclass of JComponent. I'm not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: I've searched some other stackoverflow answer, and someone suggested putting revalidate() method before the repaint(). I tried that, but nothing is different.